# How to validate the request (query & body) parameter in controller using sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Here is my controller, I want to validate body parameter like name and mobile, email, etc. How to do that.

/**

- RegisterController
- 
- @description :: Server-side actions for handling incoming requests.
- @help        :: See https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/actions
  */

module.exports = {

register:async(req,res,next)=>{
return res.send({ 'status': 'success','message':'registration successfully'},200);
}

};

Answer (score 0):

Sails.js provides a feature called **model attributes**. By defining model attributes, Sails automatically takes care of most of the validation based on the attributes that you define.

Checkout https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes to learn more about model attributes.

Additionally you can validate the request body data by using regular JavaScript validation methods and regular expressions(for mobile and email).